# Can Diameter Final unit indication avp be used over Gx interface?

Tags: diameter-protocol

Can the Diameter Final unit indication avp be used over Gx interface?

I know its available over Gy, but can I use it between pcrf and pcef?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), please make your question [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for coding question which can be reproduced by others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

YES

Take a look in the GX specification 29212-b70.
If you look at the CCR you can find Charging-Rule-Report AVP. This is a grouped AVP that includes Final-Unit-Indication AVP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As per Gx reference point (3GPP specs 29212 v13.5). Charging-Rule-Report AVP contains the Final-Unit-Indication AVP. It indicates the termination action the PCEF applies to the PCC rules.